# Using Twitch's API to get multiple channels with one request

Tags: php, api, twitch

I am using Twitch's API to request some details about a user, in particular I need to get their: twitch user, channel, live channel

I am having no problem getting any of their details, I have it set up so I can get a bulk amount of users with one request. The same with their live channels. But with just getting channel information, according to Twitch's API I must send a request per user. I can't see anyway to get a bulk list of channels

For example, using the code posted below, I can get 10-100s of users twitch user data  in one simple request

But when I try to send too many requests I get blocked from their API

**Code for getting bulk twitch user data**

```
public static function setTwitchUserBulk($users)
{
    // Key by their twitch_id
    $users = $users->keyBy('twitch_id');

    $twitch_key = env('TWITCH_KEY');
    $url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users?';

    foreach($users as $user) {

        $url .= 'login='.$user->twitch_username.'&';
    }

    $data = \App\CustomHelper\ZarlachTwitchHelper::_basicCURL($url, array(
        'Client-ID' => $twitch_key,
    ));

    $data = json_decode($data, true);

    if(isset($data['data'])) {
        $data = $data['data'];

        foreach($data as $twitchUser) {

            if(isset($users[$twitchUser['id']])) {

                // ... handle and store their data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[According to Twitch's API](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/reference/channels/#get-channel-by-id), I must use this URL to get their channel

`GET https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/<channel ID>`

Where as, when I get their twitch user, I can simply keep adding parameters onto the url to set the users i want to fetch

`GET https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users?login=<user IDs>`

Comment: So what's the question? You get blocked after too many requests? That's a common thing in APIs is being blocked after n requests. It's so one user doesn't overload their servers. You can probably apply or pay for more access to Twitch's API

Comment: If you want an increase in your rate, you can go here https://dev.twitch.tv/limit-increase/